# The meaning of “make strong showing”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> This faculty **<strike>make</strike> makes a strong showing** on the list of highly cited
> researchers.

What is the meaning of ‘make a strong showing’? And what are some good synonyms for it?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strong-showing) includes that collocation. The faculty is on the list, perhaps near the top. It is just an adjective and a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/showing) defines showing as:

> the quality of someone's performance in a competition

A strong showing therefore means performing well.

For a list of highly cited researchers, making a strong showing could mean that a large number of faculty members appear in the list, or that those faculty members whose names do appear in the list are near the top of the list (ie most frequently cited), or even a combination of the two.

As for synonyms, you could replace "make a strong showing" with "perform well".